# Which of the Mizvot are the most complicated to adhere to in the modern USA?

Tags: mitzvah

Which of the Mitzvot are the most complicated/difficult to adhere to in the modern USA?

Comment: My guess is shmitta :-)

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: Not serving *avodah zarah* (America).

Comment: living in Israel

Comment: It would help to know what you mean by "complicated".

Answer (score 1):

Yitgabber k'ari. Manlihood and lions are not liked by many parts of the machine. I know SAOC 1:1 is talking about Early Rising but I'm reading it slower and wider.